# drawing points coordinates in a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, coordinates

I need to draw points coordinates in a graph. In my case, the problem is that the values of the x-axis and y-axis of each point can be very large. That is why I need to edit the code below in order to be able to draw the 2D points even for large coordinates values.

For example the code below works well but only for small coordinates values, I need to use it for large coordinates values without increasing the graph. Let us consider a point A(300,200).

Any help will be very appreciated!

The code is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{automata,topaths}% note neded for this.
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=0.4cm]

 \draw[latex-latex, thin, draw=gray] (-4,0)--(4,0) node [right] {$x$}; % l'axe des abscisses
 \draw[latex-latex, thin, draw=gray] (0,-5)--(0,5) node [above] {$y$}; % l'axe des ordonnées

\foreach \Point in {(-2,1.5), (-1,1), (-2,3), (-1,2.5), (1,3)}{
    \node at \Point {\textbullet};
}

\foreach \Point in {(2,-1.5), (1,-1), (2,-3), (1,-2.5), (1,-3)}{
    \node at \Point {$\circ$};
}

% to ensure that the points are being properly centered:
\draw [dotted, gray] (-4,-6) grid (5,5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)? An example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61322/1952

Comment: @lgnasi, thank you, this help well! please put your comment in an answer in order to vote up and accept your answer :) Because you resolved my problem

Comment: Harish already did it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `pgfplots` and diffrent styles for different sets of numbers

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=5.5in,compat=1.10}

 \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
                xlabel = $x$,
                x label style={at={(1.04,0.5)}},
                ylabel = $y$,
                y label style={at={(0.5,1.05)}},
                xmin=-600,
                xmax=600,
                ymin=-5000,
                ymax=5000,
                xtick={-600,-500,-400,-300,-200,-100,100,200,300,400,500,600},
                ytick={-5000,-4000,-3000,-2000,-1000,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000},
                enlargelimits]
\addplot[
scatter,
only marks,
point meta=explicit symbolic,
scatter/classes={
a={mark=square*,blue},%
b={mark=triangle*,red},%
c={mark=o,draw=black}},
]
      table[meta=label] {
      x y label
      100 2000 a
      200 3000 c
      -400 2500 a
      500 4200 a
      200 -1000 b
      250 -1500 c
      400 -3000 b
      };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution for fun with `tkz-euclide` package:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

 \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-600,xmax=600, xstep=100,
  ymin=-5000, ymax=5000,ystep=1000]
  \tkzAxeXY
  \tkzDefSetOfPoints[prefix=P]{%
        100/2000,
        200/3000,
        -400/2500,
        500/4200,
        200/-1000,
        250/-1500,
        400/-3000}
  \tkzDrawPoints[fill=black](P1,P2,P3,P4)
\tkzDrawPoints[fill=orange](P5,P6,P7)
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution. Run it with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

 \begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(-6.2,-5.1)(7,6)
  \psaxes[dx=2,Dx=200,dy=2,Dy=2000]{->}(0,0)(-6,-5)(6.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \pslistplot[xunit=0.01,yunit=0.001,plotstyle=dots,dotstyle=square*,linecolor=red]{
     100 2000 200 3000  -400 2500 500 4200  200 -1000 250 -1500  400 -3000}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]